# Words for before, during and after a theatrical performance?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for words that refer to the following, in a theatre or cinema context:

- before the performance (i.e. when people are making their way in, getting to their seats, etc)
- during the performance (I guess this would just be the "performance", but is there a more specific term for the period of time that the main event is 'live'?)
- after the performance (when people are making their way out, and music is playing)

Any ideas?

Comment: _Pre-performance, performance, post-performance_. If you need single words. Descriptions are better.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree fully with you. *You may wish to order your interval drinks before the performance*. *Please ensure that your mobile phones are switched to silent, during the performance*. *The restaurant remains open after the performance*.

Comment: @WS2 Unless the bear has chased everyone away.

Comment: whoever downvoted, please comment to say why

Comment: During the show you normally would refer to speech as **Dialogue**

Comment: Prelude/postlude, prolog/epilog, or overture/finale.

Comment: I upvoted - do I have to say why too?

Comment: @callum That sort of courtesy seems beyond the reach of some people on the site, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

The French provide the answer here. We use [après](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apr%C3%A8s) for 'after', most commonly in 'après-ski', which literally means 'after skiing'. So for after a performance, 'après-show'.

'Before' in French is [avant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/before), which is in fairly regular usage, either just by itself, '*avant*', or more specifically as per the question, 'avant-show'.

During the performance is more difficult. The French for 'now' is [maintenant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-french/now), which doesn't really work in English. And during the performance we are active, and so perhaps the relatively inactive states of before and after a performance need dealing with separately.

Comment: The trouble is, they don't seem to be commonly used by anglophones. Please add evidence before I decide this answer is unhelpful.

Comment: How do those differ from "before", "during", and "after", other than sounding hoity-toity.

Comment: @HotLicks they also differ just by being uncommon, which is exactly what I'm looking for. Not just for the sake of being different, but so I can use them as names for sections of something.

Comment: @Edwin - depends on who you know I guess - v..common amongst my friends, and they ain't all English; Hot Licks, meet Callum, Callum,.. Hot Licks.

Comment: I've just been looking at a book on some delightful French villages. I'm trying to think of a more convincing reason not to downvote.

Comment: http://www.french-property.com/vp/nv/ds/aquitaine-pyr%C3%A9n%C3%A9es-atlantiques-lescar-house/id/518829/